# How to Identify Bandwidth rate of TCP Client

Tags: c#, bandwidth

I'm sending bulk data to client from my C# server application. Different clients may have  different amounts of bandwidth available.  For example, some clients may be using dial-up, broadband, etc.

A low-bandwidth client will be unable to get my data quickly,  which may cause blocking in my server application.

I'm retrying the send 5 times to clients, if the data is not successfully received. I need to restrict data send by my server by tracking the bandwidth rate of clients.

How can I determine the bandwidth rate of receiving client in C# ?

Comment: You keep track of when the upload started using an async thread update to update control on the main form. You will want to keep track of how much was uploaded, how much is left to upload, and how long it has been since the upload started. If you divide how much you uploaded by 1024 you can get how an estimate on many KB/sec the user is uploading at.  You could also just upload the file in its own thread and report the progress back to the main thread.

Comment: How are you sending the data back to the client?  Did you write the client side software as well?

Comment: that's a really bad idea to try figuring this out from the server. though from the client, its very doable

Comment: @ Robaticus : Yes.I have a Client software as well. Some DialUp clients or clients receiving in low bandwidth affects data transfer of Good bandwidth clients. So , i want to restrict resending data according to the capability of clients . For eg.Resend data only 2 times for low bandwidth and 5 times for Good bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a very good approach, since bandwidth to any particular client can change dramatically.

Instead, implement some flow control (TCP provides this for you).  Probably the only thing you need to do is configure your socket for non-blocking I/O, so it gives an error message when the transmit window fills instead of blocking your thread.